# Handling $\max(x,0)$ in the objective function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following optimization problem in $x$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \max (K_1+x,0)+ K_2 x\\ \text{subject to} & \quad x \in \mathcal{P}\end{array}$$

Is there any trick to handle $\max(\cdot,0)$ and convert this optimization problem into a linear program?

Comment: In fact, the objective in a LP can always be taken to be a single variable (by adding an extra variable as necessary). $\min\{\max(a,b,c...) | ...\}$ is equivalent to $\min\{ \alpha | a \le \alpha, b \le \alpha, ... , ... \}$.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achieved by adding one dummy variable.
\begin{align}
\min_P \quad &(\max (K_1+P,0)+ K_2 P)\\ P &\in \mathcal{P}\\& \Updownarrow\\
\min_P\quad &t+K_2P\\P&\in \mathcal{P}\\t&\geq K_1+P\\t&\geq0
\end{align}

Comment: What would the variable t become in a maximization model to avoid unboundedness?